# MOD REWRITE (BASE) on WAMP Server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp, radix

I have an WAMP webserver with Rewrite module activated.

I have all my projects in:

```
d:/prj/costumer1/www/ (alias: costumer1)
d:/prj/costumer2/www/ (alias: costumer2)
and so on...
```

For costumer1 I have an .htaccess-file that works just fine. Looking like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /costumer1/
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?/([[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?/([[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?/([[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [QSA]
```

Now when I create a src/href-link I now have to use:

```
/costumer1/search/book/novell    (aka: costumer1/?a=search&b=book&c=novell)
```

instead of

```
/search/book/novell    (aka: costumer1/?a=search&b=book&c=novell)
```

So in short:

I don't want to write "/costumer1" in front of every link: `<a href="/costumer1/search/">search</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something like this in my root `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^customer1$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/customer1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ customer1/$1 [L,NS]
```

But eventually, I moved away from handling this with `.htaccess` as it was less scalable, and went on to setting [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html), something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "D:/htdocs/customer1"
  ServerName customer1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "D:/htdocs/customer2"
  ServerName customer2
</VirtualHost>
```

And for this to work, of course edit your hosts file, to have lines like this:

```
127.0.0.1       customer1
127.0.0.1       customer2
```

Comment: Thanks DannyB. You just saved me a whole lot of trouble :) VirutalHost it is!

Comment: Great. Its really an easier way to have complete separation. Your vhost config file should be under apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf.